# Split sql results into consistent but arbitrary cohorts

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to find a PostgreSQL function that will split my query results arbitrarily but consistently. Right now I'm cohorting my query results by doing an `NTILE` on a `UUID`, but its very expensive. Is there a function that will do a less expensive and arbitrary split of my results, such that consecutive runs of the same query will yield the same results?

example

```
with t_table as (
select *, NTILE(100) over uuid as part from table
)
select * from t_table where part=1
```

A function like how I'm using `NTILE` above that has consistent results but is less expensive?

Comment: If you are using `with` and `ntile()`, then you are not using MySQL.  Add the appropriate database tag.  Also, what do you mean "arbitrarily but consistently"?

Comment: Right -- this is PostgreSQL. Basically, the function I want wouldnt have to do an expensive sort and cohorting of results, but just return a consistent partition of the results for selection.

Comment: I still don't understand what "consistent" partition really means.

Comment: What other columns do you have available? Can you find one that's indexed and has a distribution that you can split into ranges?

Comment: @Gordon I'm thinking of some kind of hash. Something that isn't based on a random ordering that changes across multiple executions of the query.

Comment: provide full details of the table/columns including indexes (DDL) and some sample data, then the "expected result" from that sample data.